# Opening another view controller using delegate?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to IOS, creating a custom calendar where if the user selects any date, the app will redirect to another viewController.

I used this link to create a calendar:
https://github.com/Akhilendra/calenderAppiOS

I have done it with delegate but I can't figure out what I did wrong.

My code:

```
protocol SelectedDateDelagate: class {
    func openAppointmentDetails()
}
class CalenderView: UIView, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, MonthViewDelegate {

    weak var delegate: SelectedDateDelagate?
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell=collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
        cell?.backgroundColor=Colors.darkRed
        let lbl = cell?.subviews[1] as! UILabel
        lbl.textColor=UIColor.yellow

        let calcDate = indexPath.row-firstWeekDayOfMonth+2

        print("u selected date",calcDate,monthName)

        delegate?.openAppointmentDetails()
    }
}


class ViewController: UIViewController,SelectedDateDelagate {
    func openAppointmentDetails() {

        let myVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "appointmentDetailsVC") as! AppointmentDetailsViewController

        navigationController?.pushViewController(myVC, animated: true)

    }
}
```

now the problem is when I clicked on date nothing gonna happen.

Comment: Did you debug this? What is `myVC`'s value before pushing it on the navigation controller? Also, is `delegate` set before calling `openAppointmentDetails()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this. I forgot to add  calenderView.delegate = self
        in viewDidLoad() method of  ViewController

and also changes in openAppointmentDetails()

here are the changes.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,SelectedDateDelagate {
func openAppointmentDetails() {

    let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
    let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "appointmentDetailsVC") as! AppointmentDetailsViewController
    self.present(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
   calenderView.delegate = self
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use the storyboard in this case, and control-drag your collection view to the second view controller. Since you don't use your delegate for anything else other than presenting the view controller, you might as well just get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

Delegates are used in other cases. In this situation, it is not necessary. In addition, you do not need to conform UIView to Delegates and DataSource because it contradicts MVC. Instead, put the calendar view (collection view) inside the UIViewController and conform this controller to implement methods.

You should do this:

```
class CalenderViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

var calenderView: UICollectionView!

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)!
    cell.backgroundColor = Colors.darkRed
    let lbl = cell.subviews[1] as! UILabel
    lbl.textColor = UIColor.yellow

    let calcDate = indexPath.row - firstWeekDayOfMonth + 2

    openAppointmentDetails()
}

func openAppointmentDetails() {
    let appointmentVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "appointmentDetailsVC") as! AppointmentDetailsViewController
    navigationController?.pushViewController(appointmentVC, animated: true)
}
}
```